# Cocos Creator face to pointer

Tags: pointers, angle

i am struggling with angles in cocos creator.
I am trying to make my sprite facing my mouse when i am moving it. But i cant make it at all.
Image shows what i want to accomplish
[image: Problem]

I wanna from this gun to move and face the mouse, just like crosshair.

Ive done some coding, and this is what i have for now:

```
        var canvas = cc.find('Canvas');
    canvas.on('touchmove',function(event){
        var pos = this.node.getPosition();
        var ang = pos.angle(event.getLocation());
        var degr = cc.misc.radiansToDegrees(ang);
        this.node.setRotation(degr);
        console.log(degr);
    },this);
```

This is in onLoad function and connected to my gun sprite.

Comment: i am sure those tags are wrong. Dont know what cocos creator is but I bet it has some tags

Comment: i mean, this code works tho. The problem is with degrees, i am getting weard output